# Knockout extender restarting all model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Everything was fine until I decided to add some extenders to my view model.

I am just doing copy-paste from the [knockout docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html). What I need is to force some fields to be numeric (in this example I am using the required extend).

The problem is that all my model gets restarted when I change the extended property. How do I know it? Because all fields get initial values.

```
var ProductToAddVM = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.style = ko.observable().extend({ required: "Please enter a first name" });
    self.children = ko.computed(function () { return "something computed" }
};

var PurchaseVM = function () {
     var self = this;
     self.newInvoiceNewProduct = ko.observable(new ProductToAddVM());
};

ko.extenders.required = function (target, overrideMessage) {
        //add some sub-observables to our observable
        target.hasError = ko.observable();
        target.validationMessage = ko.observable();

        //define a function to do validation
        function validate(newValue) {
            target.hasError(newValue ? false : true);
            target.validationMessage(newValue ? "" : overrideMessage || "This field is required");
        }

        //initial validation
        validate(target());

        //validate whenever the value changes
        target.subscribe(validate);

        //return the original observable
        return target;
    };

$(document).ready(function() {
        ko.applyBindings(PurchaseVM);
});
```

What Am I missing?

### Update

here is my fiddle. Why is my model restarting? I am usre it is reastarting because It is making the ajax calls to load my model (not in fiddle)

http://jsfiddle.net/btordz/S8fZ4/1/

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?  It appears all of your problems are syntax, not closing brackets and parans and such.

Comment: You are missing a `new`: `ko.applyBindings(new PurchaseVM);` http://jsfiddle.net/3H6k5/

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it I was really desesperated

Answer (score 1):

Look here for your syntax errors -

http://jsfiddle.net/y3P9P/

```
var ProductToAddVM = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.style = ko.observable().extend({ required: "Please enter a first name" });
    self.children = ko.computed(function () { return "something computed" }); 
}
```

There are others...

Comment: thanks, I was creating the fiddle, and it is not working. I will see your exmaple +1.

Comment: Sure, check the fiddle and update it to show me what isn't working and I can help from there but after basic syntax I assume it is just that.

Comment: Maybe my binding is wrong, I get the same bug http://jsfiddle.net/btordz/S8fZ4/1/